# How to use Python XML findall to find '<v:imagedata r:id="rId7" o:title="1-REN"/>'

Tags: python, xml, vml, urn

I'm trying to do a find all from a Word document for `<v:imagedata r:id="rId7" o:title="1-REN"/>` with namespace `xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"` and I cannot figure out what on earth the syntax is.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) only cover the very straight forward case and with the URN and VML combo thrown in I can't seem to get any of the examples I've seen online to work. Does anyone happen to know what it is?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
namespace = {'v': "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"}

results = ET.fromstring(xml).findall("imagedata", namespace)
for image_id in results:
    print(image_id)
```

Edit: What @aneroid wrote is 1000% the right answer and super helpful. You should upvote it. That said, after understanding all that - I went with the BS4 answer because it does the entire job in two lines exactly how I need it to . If you don't actually care about the namespaces it seems waaaaaaay easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ET.findall()` vs `BS4.find_all()`:

- [ElementTree's `findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) is not recursive *by default<sup>*</sup>*. It's only going to **find direct children** of the node provided. So in your case, it's only searching for image nodes directly under the root element.

  - <sup>*</sup> as per [mzjn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110439/how-to-use-python-xml-findall-to-find-vimagedata-rid-rid7-otitle-1-ren/62111142?noredirect=1#comment109861839_62111142) below, prefixing the `match` argument (tag or path) with `".//"` will search for that node **anywhere in the tree**, since it's [supports XPath's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example).
- [BeautifulSoup's `find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) **searches all descendants**. So it seaches for 'imagedata' nodes anywhere in the tree.
- However, [`ElementTree.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) does **search all descendants**. Using the ['working with namespaces' example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces):

  ```
  >>> for char in root.iter('{http://characters.example.com}character'):
  ...     print(' |-->', char.text)
  ...
   |--> Lancelot
   |--> Archie Leach
   |--> Sir Robin
   |--> Gunther
   |--> Commander Clement
  ```
- Sadly, [`ET.iterfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iterfind) which works with namespaces as a dict (like ET.findall), also **does not search descendants**, only direct children *by default<sup>*</sup>*. Just like ET.findall. Apart from how empty strings `''` in the tags are treated wrt the namespace, and one returns a list while the other returns an iterator, I can't say there's a meaningful difference between `ET.findall` and `ET.iterfind`.

  - <sup>*</sup> As above for `ET.findall()`, prefixing `".//"` makes it search the entire tree (*matches with any node*).

---

When you use the namespaces with ET, you still need the *namespace name* with the tag. The results line should be:

```
namespace = {'v': "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"}
results = ET.fromstring(xml).findall("v:imagedata", namespace)  # note the 'v:'
```

Also, the `'v'` doesn't need to be a `'v'`, you could change it to something more meaningful if needed:

```
namespace = {'image': "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"}
results = ET.fromstring(xml).findall("image:imagedata", namespace)
```

<del>Of course, this still won't necessarily get you all the imagedata elements if they aren't direct children of the root. For that, you'd need to create a recursive function to do it for you. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30098154/1431750) for how. Note, while that answer does a recursive search, you are likely to hit Python's recursion limit if the descendant depth is too...*deep*.</del>

To get all the imagedata elements anywhere in the tree, use the `".//"` prefix:

```
results = ET.fromstring(xml).findall(".//v:imagedata", namespace)
```

Comment: `findall` can find all `imagedata` nodes. Just use `findall(".//v:imagedata", namespace)`.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited and clarified my answer wrt `ET.findall()`, as well as `ET.iterfind()`.

Answer (score 18):

With ElementTree in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#xml), you can simply use a wildcard (`{*}`) for the namespace:

```
results = ET.fromstring(xml).findall(".//{*}imagedata")
```

Note the `.//` part, which means that the whole document (all descendants) is searched.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave the question open, but the workaround I'm currently using is to use BeautifulSoup which happily accepts the `v:` syntax.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")

results = soup.find_all("v:imagedata")
```