# xml.etree.ElementTree findall function returns empty string for path python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

Given XML as string :

```
xml_as_string = """<root xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://w/e">
    <Context operation="something.wsdl">
        <SOAP_Version>123.321</SOAP_Version>
        <Namespace xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://dummy.com"/>
    </Context>
    <Header/>
    <Body>
        <ns2:Complex xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.this/idk">
            <ns2:simple>
                <ns2:child1>IKM</ns2:child1>
                <ns2:child2>1234</ns2:child2>
                <ns2:child3>S</ns2:child3>
            </ns2:simple>
            <ns2:simple>
                <ns2:child1>QEw</ns2:child1>
                <ns2:child2>10028111</ns2:child2>
                <ns2:parentchild1>IKM</ns2:parentchild1>
                <ns2:parentchild2>1234</ns2:parentchild2>
                <ns2:child3>S</ns2:child3>
            </ns2:simple>
            <ns2:simple>
                <ns2:child1>IOW</ns2:child1>
                <ns2:child2>100043896</ns2:child2>
                <ns2:parentchild1>QEw</ns2:parentchild1>
                <ns2:parentchild2>10028111</ns2:parentchild2>
            </ns2:simple>
            <ns2:extra>
                <ns2:childextra>0</ns2:childextra>
            </ns2:extra>
        </ns2:Complex>
    </Body>
</root>
"""
```

Creating xml tree using xml.etree.ElementTree:

```
`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

root = ET.fromstring(xml_as_string)
```

For a specific path, I'm trying to print all the values found

```
path = './Body/Complex/simple/child1'

path_vals = root.findall(path)
print([e.text for e in path_vals])
```

The result is an empty list :

```
[]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in python ?

Comment: u need to include the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want all the text associated with child1 : You need to use the [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) to get the data : "http://www.test.this/idk" is the namespace

```
namespace = '{http://www.test.this/idk}'

[ent.text for ent in root.findall(F".//{namespace}child1")]

['IKM', 'QEw', 'IOW']
```

If you want to do away with the namespaces, you could give [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) a go :

```
from parsel import Selector
selector = Selector(xml_as_string, 'xml')

#remove namespace
selector.remove_namespaces()

#get your required text
selector.xpath(".//child1/text()").getall()

['IKM', 'QEw', 'IOW']
```

Comment: u could pass it as a variable, then use fstrings.

Comment: Hmm, then idealy i'd prefer something that either ignores namespaces or figures them out by itself, hmm, looking into lxml rn, maybe, just maybe

Comment: edited code, using [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: With ElementTree in Python 3.8, you can use a wildcard for the namespace. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117710/407651.