# python, xml.etree, Parsing XML with Namespaces

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I have something like this

```
for country in root.findall('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0}body/{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0}text/{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0}table/{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0}table-row/{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0}table-cell'):
```

How can I shorten it?

`{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0}body`

and

`{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0}table-cell`

are different, at "office" and "table"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/5386938

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Comment: With Python 3.8 and later, you can use a wildcard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117710/407651.

Comment: yeah, that works @mzjn .//{*}