# root.findall() doesn't find anything when specifying the namespace dynamically

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am reading through some XML files where the namespace differs for each of them. Problem is, when I say `ns={"x":root.tag}`, and say root.findall it doesn't find anything. On the other hand, instead of root.tag if I specify the actual namespace string like, "https://schemas...." whatever, then the findall is working.

Here is my code, see from `ns={"x":root.tag}`

```
def parse_csprojForNuGetPackages(repository_root, repository_name, source):
    try:
        p=os.path.join(repository_root,repository_name,source)
        with open(p,encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            file_content=f.read().replace('\n','')
            root=ET.fromstring(str(file_content))
    except Exception as ex:
        return None

         # Extract the list of NuGet packages that are used by the csproj file.
    print(root.tag)
    
    ns={"x":root.tag}
    for element in root.findall('.//x:PackageReference',ns): #I want all PackageReference elements with its attributes in the xml file.
        ref = PackageReference(
            ecosystem = 'NuGet',
            repository_root = repository_root,
            repository_name = repository_name,
            source = source,
            package_name = element.attrib['Include'],
            version = element.find('.//x:Version',ns).text) #element.attrib['Version'])
        refs.append(ref) #Get all the Nuget Packages.  

    return refs
```

For instance some of xmls can be like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

or it can be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{F3B4CDC7-94F8-40BF-AB48-9920A873A6DD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Labcyte.Core.Server</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CoreServer</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;-c -s</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>
    </StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug-Linux|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug-Linux\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug-Linux|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug-Linux\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-Linux|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release-Linux\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;-c -s</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-Linux|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release-Linux\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration.Install" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="CmdProcessor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Config.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Host.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SSLCommandProcessor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utils.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Include="SimulationData\3FeatureFullCapture1pt20V.csv">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.Core.Daq\Labcyte.Core.Daq.csproj">
      <Project>{1b8c9428-1378-46c4-9bca-2e5d5365e256}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.Daq</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.Core.Interface\Labcyte.Core.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{680bc720-71fa-4377-8b31-50267a538d5f}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.Core.IScript\Labcyte.Core.IScript.csproj">
      <Project>{4f92afb1-000b-44e1-9823-98de10ce72b0}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.IScript</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.Core.Math\Labcyte.Core.NumericalMethods.csproj">
      <Project>{d4bf4690-9549-4527-816b-39518618e611}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.NumericalMethods</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.Core.NLog\Labcyte.Core.NLog.csproj">
      <Project>{6e4ac4fd-b91d-4544-8d72-e502d1db7c51}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.NLog</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.Core.Script\Labcyte.Core.Script.csproj">
      <Project>{d8b06bbf-43c1-4e83-bb1f-0c8dce5470ca}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.Script</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Labcyte.License\Labcyte.License.csproj">
      <Project>{cc14afbb-6358-4358-a87a-a8219df220aa}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.License</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Labcyte.Core.Hardware\Labcyte.Core.Hardware.csproj">
      <Project>{578923d9-359d-4754-ae49-9d9d5ff40be5}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.Hardware</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Labcyte.Core.Instrument\Labcyte.Core.Instrument.csproj">
      <Project>{236787d2-8406-4072-b25e-9d1d36f77827}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Core.Instrument</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Properties\BuildDateTime.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Mono.Posix">
      <Version>4.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms">
      <Version>4.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe  $(TargetDir)CoreServer.exe
$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe $(TargetDir)Labcyte.Core.Daq.dll
$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe $(TargetDir)Labcyte.Core.Hardware.dll
$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe $(TargetDir)Labcyte.Core.Instrument.dll
$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe $(TargetDir)Labcyte.Core.Interface.dll
$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe $(TargetDir)Labcyte.Core.NLog.dll
$(SolutionDir)..\..\ThirdParty\Mono.Unofficial.pdb2mdb\4.2.3.4\tools\pdb2mdb.exe $(TargetDir)Labcyte.Core.Script.dll
copy $(SolutionDir)\..\Installers\CoreServer\Images\rootfs\public\Labcyte.pfx $(TargetDir)
rmdir /S /Q "$(SolutionDir)..\..\Library\Core\CoreServer\"
mkdir "$(SolutionDir)..\..\Library\Core\CoreServer\"
copy "$(TargetDir)*.dll"  "$(SolutionDir)..\..\Library\Core\CoreServer\"
copy "$(TargetDir)*.pdb"  "$(SolutionDir)..\..\Library\Core\CoreServer\"

</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>del /F "$(ProjectDir)\Properties\BuildDateTime.txt"
echo %25date%25 %25time%25 &gt; "$(ProjectDir)\Properties\BuildDateTime.txt"</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: How about using a wildcard? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117710/407651

Comment: @mzjn I understand. I'm planning to remove the xml namespace with this solution in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159221/remove-namespace-and-prefix-from-xml-in-python-using-lxml.%20   and follow the wildcard pattern you suggested. Hopefully that might work.

Comment: Just use the wildcard. You don't need to remove the namespace.

Comment: Thank you let me try it out.