# Need to repeat one XML element with other element's subs in Python

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have some obscure XML files with some heavily nested elements. I'm able to parse through the elements and grab everything but am having an issue that I can't fix. There is probably a better way but I'm not super savvy in parsing XML yet.

XML File

```
<NAXML-MaintenanceRequest xmlns:vxt="urn:vfi-sapphire:np.naxmlext.2005-06-24" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.4" xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16">
  <TransmissionHeader>
    <StoreLocationID>7500</StoreLocationID>
    <VendorName>PDI</VendorName>
    <VendorModelVersion>PDI/Enterprise 11.9.01</VendorModelVersion>
  </TransmissionHeader>
  <ItemListMaintenance>
    <TableAction type="initialize" />
    <RecordAction type="addchange" confirm="no" />
    <ILTDetail>
      <RecordAction type="addchange" confirm="no" />
      <ItemListID>100</ItemListID>
      <ItemListDescription>MM\Dasani 1L</ItemListDescription>
      <ItemListEntry>
        <ItemCode>
          <POSCodeFormat format="gtin" checkDigit="present" />
          <POSCode>00049000026566</POSCode>
          <POSCodeModifier name="EACH10">0</POSCodeModifier>
        </ItemCode>
      </ItemListEntry>
    </ILTDetail>
    <ILTDetail>
      <RecordAction type="addchange" confirm="no" />
      <ItemListID>101</ItemListID>
      <ItemListDescription>MM\Vitamin Water 20oz</ItemListDescription>
      <ItemListEntry>
        <ItemCode>
          <POSCodeFormat format="gtin" checkDigit="present" />
          <POSCode>00786162150004</POSCode>
          <POSCodeModifier name="EACH5">0</POSCodeModifier>
        </ItemCode>
      </ItemListEntry>
      <ItemListEntry>
        <ItemCode>
          <POSCodeFormat format="gtin" checkDigit="present" />
          <POSCode>00786162002976</POSCode>
          <POSCodeModifier name="EACH5">0</POSCodeModifier>
        </ItemCode>
      </ItemListEntry>
    </ILTDetail>
  </ItemListMaintenance>
</NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
```

I'm trying to grab the ItemListID and any corresponding POSCode that is assigned to it. When I tried I was only able to get each value but not put them together. I am sure my method is too many steps but it's what I could understand current state.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
import os, os.path, sys
import csv

itemFile = "myfilepathhere.xml"
tree = ET.parse(itemFile)
root = tree.getroot()

# Returns key value pairs #
def extract_elements(element, path='', elements=None):
    if elements is None:
        elements = []
    path = '/'.join([path, element.tag]) if path else element.tag
    for child in element:
        if len(child) == 0:
            elements.append({'Path': child.tag, 'Value': child.text})
        else:
            extract_elements(child, path, elements)
    return elements

all_elements = []
for record in root:
    all_elements.extend(extract_elements(record))
df = pd.DataFrame(all_elements)
print(df)
```

If there's a better path I'd appreciate it. Ideally the result would be

| ItemListID | POSCode |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 00049000026566 |
| 101 | 00786162150004 |
| 101 | 00786162002976 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each `ILTDetail`, make a list of dicts and pass it to the [`DataFrame`](https://ILTDetail) constructor :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd    

elems = ET.parse("file.xml").findall(".//{*}ILTDetail")

df =  pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "ItemListID": det.findtext("{*}ItemListID"),
            "POSCode": psc.text
        } for det in elems for psc in det.findall(".//{*}POSCode")
    ]
)
```

Output :

```py
print(df)

  ItemListID         POSCode
0        100  00049000026566
1        101  00786162150004
2        101  00786162002976

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was able to pull all the values exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Pandas only solution**
Using `pandas.read_xml()` with `iterparse` feature and then "reshaping" the dataframe.
Up to 3 `POSCode` elements were considered for each `ItemListID`

```
iterdict = {"ILTDetail": ["ItemListID", "POSCode", "POSCode", "POSCode"]}
names = ["ItemListID", "POSCode1", "POSCode2","POSCode3"]
df_tmp = pd.read_xml('tmp2', iterparse=iterdict, dtype=object, names=names)
df = pd.melt(df_tmp, id_vars=names[0], value_vars=names[1:], value_name="POSCode").dropna()[["ItemListID","POSCode"]
```

Result

```
0        100  00049000026566
1        101  00786162150004
2        102  00786162003458
4        101  00786162002976
5        102  00786162004621
8        102  00786162021870
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `findall` or `iterfind` method and search by XPATH,  e.g. (example updated, thanks @mzjn):

```py
tree = ET.parse('<xml file>')
details = tree.findall('.//{*}ILTDetail')
for detail in detail:
    itemListID, POSCode = detail[1].text, detail[3][0][1].text
    ...
```

The indexes are about getting the nth child, i.e. `detail[3][0][1]` means: get the 4th child of detail, get the first child of the result, then get the second child of the last result. (indexes a 0 based)

Beside this, lxml library does also offer a ElementTree interface it's usage is very similar to xml.etree. But it's easier to use:

```py
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('<xml file>')
details = tree.findall(".//{*}ILTDetail")
```

Comment: You can use a wildcard for the namespace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117710/407651.

Comment: @mzjn: that's cool, thanks. I updated the example.

Comment: Thank you for this, lxml does have some easy to use features that I'm looking into now.